# How to load Blazor component in MVC partial view from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor

I have MVC .net 6 project which has a lot of partial views.
When I want to dynamically load partial view by clicking on some element I have to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                $partialPlaceholder.html(data);          
            }});
```

But the Blazor component which is inside that partial view won't be properly loaded:

1. Server render mode will leave an empty tag like this:

```
<!--Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8B99I0cbbItAhZMgQjSIqXhJKeLkYV1Xkv3sOuZEwlnX9K3nAexD73o6LSCwe7KAcr5PSyQ0v2MGUtpX/9Lcp1EtxWGUDbHI1xB3WhU4FZJ6gM2rhbmB\u002BU2kGlrOXdlQKh\u002BJeoWHJVx2QwHV7oTqf\u002BYKrdJNM4yeHzc5cAKR6CcoDU5OML2z2sX2Cixy6jxgAEyarks7sVmFW9UVlEbqDgxSGZFgiJHRITkr0STkdoba4eVwVTxbqloWHUOVv6CPXqoV7NyOTJiiUGLPQLIIAyj1oQjjKys7mjcA1CaKUG4Y2TrM7GtDdnOBWl72cpsl6\u002Bbaf8MggGFm2l7UmoTS3U81EoGSbxWdVjpCXlzpmb\u002B8uofdD6iP3SC\u002B0JASevvFVA=="}-->
```

2. ServerPrerendered mode will render component but it  will not be interactive, like it is not connected to hub

If I render component like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27574)

```
Blazor.renderComponent(element, { componentName: "ShoppingCart" }, parameters: { shoppingCartId: "asdf" });
```

then it will have multiple root components which I don't want to.
What is the proper way of loading razor components in partial?

Comment: I believe that blazor.server.js needs to know about the components it has to manage when it starts up i.e. when the page loads in the browser.  If you add them later - dynamically - then they aren't "registered" and they don't get rendered.   Without more detail it's difficult to make a recommendation.  I would suggest adding the components upfront and then turning them on and off, but that may not fit with your design ....  who knows?

Comment: Well yes, I was thinking that I might need to add some additional code in javascript after I render partial because it will just put plain HTML inside some element and Blazor server should somehow know it should interact with it, but I can't find anywhere that something like that exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is one "hack" solution to this.
Putting `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` right after component in partial will make it interactive (and render it also in case of server mode) but will create an additional signalR circuit and won't work in case there are multiple components on the same page to render.